# Can a partial have two models from different sources?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a partial set for a logged in user of type **student** and **teacher**. 
Both share the same database table.

In my index model I have a user variable which would wold the currently logged in user data:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            AspNetUser CurrentUser = null;
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                CurrentUser = this.Db.AspNetUsers.Single(g => g.Id == userID);
            }
            else
            {
                studentIndex.CurrentUser = null;
            }

            return View(CurrentUser);
        }
```

The index view file then checks one parameter, and depending on it, calls an appropriate partial action

```
if (Model.CurrentUser.ClassId != 0) //classID = 0 is reserved for teachers
    {
        Html.RenderAction("_StudentIndexView", "Home"); 
    }
```

The partial action looks like this:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _StudentIndexView ()
{
    return PartialView(this.Db.classes.ToList());
}
```

Now in my Partial View I would like to have both the **classes** from the _studentIndexView controller and also access to the **user information**.

What is the proper way to get vaules from both sources in one controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ViewModel should contain everything it needs to render the view, including the partial. In your case the it needs `CurrentUser` and `classes`. I'm assuming for the sake of the examples below these are of type `AspNetUser` and `List<Class>`. This means that your model needs to be something like

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public AspNetUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
    public List<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

you would then set up the whole model in `Index` giving you

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    AspNetUser currentUser = null;
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        currentUser = this.Db.AspNetUsers.Single(g => g.Id == userID);
    }

    var model = new IndexModel
                    {
                        CurrentUser = currentUser,
                        Classes = this.Db.classes.ToList()
                    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Your view would then use this model and would have both `CurrentUser` and `Classes` available as follows

```
@model IndexModel

//some stuff using Model.CurrentUser where needed

if (Model.CurrentUser.ClassId != 0) //classID = 0 is reserved for teachers
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_StudentIndexView", Model);
}

//more stuff using Model.CurrentUser where needed
```

By rendering the partial directly in the view you can get rid of `_StudentIndexView` from the controller unless you need it for something else (e.g. an AJAX call).

Your partial, which now needs access to both the classes will look like

```
@model IndexModel

//the content of your view using Model.CurrentUser and Model.Classes where required.
```